# Adding 'Value' to a Tuple

Tags: haskell

Im trying to add more 'data' into a player database but I'm getting some unexpected results:

data type declaration:

```hs
data Player= Player teamName player goals
    deriving (Show, Read)
type teamName = String
type player = String
type goals = [Int]
```

```hs
db :: [Players]
db = [
 Player "Bayern" "Lewandowski" [3, 52, 16, 3],
 Player "Tottenham" "Kane" [11, 31, 3, 2]
]
```

The code I'm using to add a new player to the database.

```hs
addPlayer :: Player -> [Players] -> [Players]
addPlayer playerInfo database = database++[playerInfo]
```

used to show all the players in the given DB:

```hs
showAllPlayers :: [Players] -> String
showAllPlayers [] =""
showAllPlayers [x] = getPlayer x
showAllPlayers (x:xs) = getPlayer x ++ "\n" ++ showAllPlayers xs
```

When attempting to run the line `addPlayer(Player "Man UTD" "Rooney" [5, 6, 2, 11]) db)` its all fine and dandy and in the console it says that this line has been added. The output:
`[Player "Bayern" "Lewandowski" [3, 52, 16, 3],Player "Tottenham" "Kane" [11, 31, 3, 2],Player "Man UTD" "Rooney" [5, 6, 2, 11]]`

But when I run the code to output all the players `putStrnLn(showAllPlayers data)` the player I tried to add is not on the list?

Comment: The code given doesn't compile. Please post [a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It should compile?

Comment: Probably because data in Haskell is *immutable* in general - you can't change the content of a data structure except the way you're doing it: writing a function which returns the "updated" data structure. That function can't possibly effect the value of the "variable" that holds the "old" data.

Comment: So you cant just stick in data? Wouldn't a solution be to copy that data into a temporary variable, add the value on top and create a new database?

Comment: as others said the solution is to `newData = addPlayer ... data` and then when you do `showAllPlayers newData` you'll see the new data too - usually you'll want to *really* mutate in some *Monad* - for example you can use a [`MVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) and update this or a [state monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html) approach  - but this really depends on your use case - for now I'd stick with *creating new* `[Player]` lists and passing those around

Answer (score 5):

`addPlayers` does not modify its database argument; instead, it returns an updated database. So the correct call is:

```
putStrLn (showAllPlayers (addPlayer (Player "Man UTD" "Rooney" [5, 6, 2, 11]) db))
```